# tortoisegit does not pull

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am new to Git. I installed msysgit, configured ssh and pulled a solution from GitHub (my own solution, I pushed it from a different computer). 
The pull worked.

Now, I installed tortoisegit to make life easier. It displays the correct items in Windows Explorer. I would expect a "pull" and push entries in the context menus, but I can't find them. Where's by mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tutorial on [using TortoiseGit with GitHub](http://wiki.github.com/multitheftauto/multitheftauto/how-to-use-tortoisegit) mentions:

> **TortoiseGit’s Sync dialog is basically one dialog with both pull and push in it**.
>   Pretty easy if you need to do either or both.
>
> Pushing your changes to your repository:
>   1/ TortoiseGit→Sync
>     - 1/ (Local and remote branches should be merge at this point, Remote URL should be origin)
>     - 2/ Push
>
> Pulling any changes from your repository:
>   1/ TortoiseGit→Sync
>     - 1/ (Local and remote branches should be merge at this point, Remote URL should be origin)
>     - 2/ Pull

See also [GitHub on Windows](http://software.krimnet.com/github-on-windows), with this picture:

[image: TortoiseGit sync]

Comment: Ouch. I was so focussed on the "TortoiseGit" submenu. Thanks, that solved it.